# python subprocess git clone

Tags: python, git, aws-lambda, subprocess

I'm using subprocess() on AWS lambda
And using this layer: https://github.com/lambci/git-lambda-layer

Here is code:

```
import json
import os

import subprocess

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    os.chdir('/tmp')

    subprocess.Popen(["git", "clone", "https:/github.com/hongmingu/requirements"], shell=True)
    subprocess.Popen(["touch word.txt"], shell=True)

    word = str(subprocess.check_output(["ls"], shell=True))
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(word)
    }
```

And it returns:

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "\"b'word.txt\\\\n'\""
}
```

So there is something wrong on `subprocess.Popen(["git", "clone", "https:/github.com/hongmingu/requirements"], shell=True)`

I checked there is git by `subprocess.check_output(["git --version"], shell=True)` and it works well.

How to solve it?

Comment: `subprocess.Popen` is non-blocking. You may want to use `subprocess.run`. And btw, If shell is `True`, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems.

First, you need to wait for the `git` process to exit. To do this with `subprocess.Popen`, call `.wait()` on the returned `Popen` object. However, I'd recommend using `subprocess.check_call()` instead to automatically wait for the process to exit and to raise an error if the process returns a non-zero exit status.

Second, there's no need to specify `shell=True` since you're not using any shell expansions or built-ins. In fact, when passing an argument list when using `shell=True`, the first item is the command string, and the remaining items are arguments to the shell itself, not the command.

Lastly, you're missing a slash in your GitHub URL.

Try this instead:

```py
subprocess.check_call(["git", "clone", "https://github.com/hongmingu/requirements"])
```